# Attempting to create dictionary pairs using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to solve a problem using dictionary pairs for several weeks.  my goal is to search each line of a text file using several regexes for date, time, lat and long and then ultimately create a new csv with just those values in each row.  I have figured out the regex to use for each item I'm searching; however, getting the data into dictionary pairs has not worked.  I was mirroring code for a regex search of email, but my results are not creating the same output.  I'm trying to create a list containing dictionary pairs as follows:
[{'date':'12/1/20', 'time': '10:41:45},{'date':'12/2/20', 'time': '10:42:45}]

what I'm getting:
[{'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': '2/5/2021', 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': '10:41:45'}]

I'm using Python 3.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

list1 = []

fh = open(r"test_data.txt", "r").read()
contents = fh.split()

for item in contents:
    list_dict = {}

    date_field = re.search(r"(\d{1})[/.-](\d{1})[/.-](\d{4})$", item)

    if date_field is not None:
        date = date_field.group()

    else:
        date = None
    list_dict["date"] = date

    time_field = re.search(r"(\d{1,2})[:](\d{2})[:](\d{2})$", item)
    if time_field is not None:
        time = time_field.group()
    else:
        time = None
    list_dict["time"] = time

    list1.append(list_dict)

print(list1)

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.to_csv("test_export_with_testdata.csv", index=False)
```

Here is some of the data I'm trying to analyze.  In other portions values such as date and time are in different columns.  It appears that the delimiter is a space so I believe splitting on a space should work.

```
Wi-Fi  Access Point "BoogiesBeachHouse" (100C6B0E4C30) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:28:41 AM  Local  41.133058  -73.343712  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "RadwanWiFi" (160C6B0E4C30) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:28:41 AM  Local  41.133058  -73.343712  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "dah" (D46A91740B4B) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:28:41 AM  Local  41.133058  -73.343712  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "RadwanWiFi" (1A0C6B0E4CB3) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:28:41 AM  Local  41.133058  -73.343712  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "WYZE_BC4CFF1C0202D3B7" (2CAA8EB31A96) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:28:41 AM  Local  41.133058  -73.343712  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "MALTESE FALCON" (605F8D4601E6) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:29:21 AM  Local  41.130736  -73.342959  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "HardingNet" (ACA31EB0F5C0) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:29:21 AM  Local  41.130736  -73.342959  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "RadwanWiFi" (1A0C6B0E4C2F) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:29:58 AM  Local  41.133155  -73.343709  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "BoogiesBeachHouse" (100C6B0E4C2F) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:29:58 AM  Local  41.133155  -73.343709  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "dah" (D46A91740B4B) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:29:58 AM  Local  41.133155  -73.343709  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "BoogiesBeachHouse" (100C6B0E4C30) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:29:58 AM  Local  41.133155  -73.343709  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "RadwanWiFi" (160C6B0E4C30) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:29:58 AM  Local  41.133155  -73.343709  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "ORBI44" (A2C9EB1A028D) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:30:53 AM  Local  41.136746  -73.342839  
Wi-Fi  Access Point "NETGEAR41" (9C3DCF177F74) detected  Access Point detected  2/6/2021 1:30:53 AM  Local  41.136746  -73.342839
```

Comment: show you input test_data.txt

Comment: post the first 10 rows of your data if you can, open it with your IDE or notepad, and literally paste the contents in here and format as code.

Comment: When first running a program like this, if you are uncomfortable using the debugger to step through code, you should be generous with print statements or logging.  For example, right at the start of your loop you could have: `print ("Analyzing item: ",item)` to verify you are processing what you think you are processing.  this would have shown you your split function for file lines is incorrect.

Comment: So I just printed the "item" and realize it basically imports every item as a string within a list.  I actually thought that was correct.  Is there a way split the data and process it line by line?  I'm new to python so any advice is helpful.

Comment: I actually was able to get it to slip by line using fh = open(r"test_data.txt", "r").read()
contents = fh.splitlines()

Comment: However, now it doesn't appear the for loop is searching anything at all.  I am returning done values for date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at your code, because you're not defining a character (or character pattern) on which to split your file, it's being split by a space. So each time you have a space in your file, you're getting a new "item". And within that string for "item", since you don't have "date" AND "time", you're going to get those None results. Obviously seeing the file would help, but I would venture a guess that that's how your file contents are formatted.

Consider putting an argument in that split call for what you want to split by. If it's a new line, then "\n" should work.